# Conexão com banco Access usando java

Tags: java, microsoft-access

Sou iniciante na programação em java, e estou tentando fazer um programa que conecte com um banco access e salve lá as informações. Criei uma classe especifica para a conexão e criei um método para inserir os dados, porem o mesmo está caindo no catch e retornando null. 
Esse código eu achei parcial na internet e alterei para minha necessidade.

```
public void Insere(Cadastro cliente )
{
    if ((cliente.getNome() != null) && (cliente.getOS() != null) && (cliente.getDataEnt() != null) && (cliente.getMarca() != null) && (cliente.getModelo() != null) && (cliente.getNS() != null) && (cliente.getValor() != null) && (cliente.getDataOrc() != null))
    {
    try 
    {
        PreparedStatement strComandoSQL;
        strComandoSQL = conexao.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Entrada(cod, Nome, Os, dataEnt, Marca, Modelo, NS, Valor, dataOrc) VALUES(?,'?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?')");
        strComandoSQL.setInt(1,cliente.getCod());
        strComandoSQL.setString(2,cliente.getNome());
        strComandoSQL.setString(3,cliente.getOS());
        strComandoSQL.setString(4,cliente.getDataEnt());
        strComandoSQL.setString(5,cliente.getMarca());
        strComandoSQL.setString(6,cliente.getModelo());
        strComandoSQL.setString(7,cliente.getNS());
        strComandoSQL.setString(8,cliente.getValor());
        strComandoSQL.setString(9,cliente.getDataOrc());
        int intRegistro = strComandoSQL.executeUpdate();
            if (intRegistro != 0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Registro adicionado !",
            "Mensagem",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            comando.close();
            conexao.close();
            }
            else
            {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Registro nao adicionado !",
            "Mensagem",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            comando.close();
            conexao.close();
            }

}
catch (Exception Excecao) 
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"SQLException: " +
    Excecao.getMessage(),"Erro: Selecao de registro",
    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
}
else
{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Falta Preencher Campo!",
"Mensagem",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
}
```

Alguém sabe o porque está retornando nulo?

A  exceção que está retornando é "null"

A pilha de erros:

> ```java
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at planilha.Banco.Insere(Banco.java:52)
>     at planilha.Planilha.actionPerformed(Planilha.java:102)
>     at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
>     at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
>     at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>     at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>     at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
>     at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
>     at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
>     at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
>     at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
>     at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
>     at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
>     at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
>     at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:747)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:718)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:717)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
> ```

Aqui o método conecta

```java
public void Conecta()
{
    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Preparando para iniciar a conexão com o BD;");

try
{
    /* Tenta se conectar ao Driver */
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

}
catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Impossível carregar o Driver.");
    System.exit(0);
}
try
{
    /* nomedobanco é o nome que você deu anteriormente ao seu alias */
    conexao = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Camptecnica");
    comando = conexao.createStatement();

}
catch (SQLException sqle)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Problema ao conectar!");
    System.exit(0);
}
 //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Conectado com sucesso!");

}
```

Comment: Bem-vindo(a) ao Stack Overflow em Português! Pode postar a exceção que está ocorrendo??

Comment: Leonardo, poste a pilha de erros na pergunta. De preferencia, adicione no seu catch um `Excecao.printStackTrace();`

Comment: Onde fica a linha 52??

Comment: é a do comando do banco "(strComandoSQL = conexao.prepareStatement("INSE...."

Comment: Sua conexão está vindo nula. A origem do problema parece não ser bem nesse método. Verifique se está iniciando corretamente a conexão antes de criar um Statement.

Comment: @diegofm você diz a conexão com o banco? Pois tem um outro método, e nele está retornando com sucesso a conexão.

Comment: Leonardo, pelo erro postado, a conexão não foi iniciada, a variável `conexao` está nula, por isso o erro. Você precisa iniciar a conexão.

Comment: @diegofm fiz o teste aqui, realmente, no método insere (), a variável conexao está vazia. Mas fiz no método conecta () está recebendo o valor. é como se limpasse depois de sair do método. Alguma sugestão do que pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: Você está chamando o método conecta antes do método insere()? Adicione ele na pergunta só pra conferencia. Ah se possivel, adicione o trecho onde você invoca o insere()(não precisa ser tudo, só um trecho com essa chamada)

Comment: @diegofm o conecta () está sendo chamado no main de outra classe e o insere num botão, dessa mesma classe.